# Prove that $\text{int} (M\times N)=\Big(\text{int} (M)\Big)\times N$, for manifolds.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Suppose that $M$ is manifold with boundary, and $N$ is a manifold without boundary. Prove that

$$\text{int} (M\times N)=\Big(\text{int} (M)\Big)\times N$$

Here is my attempt:

$\text{int} (M\times N)=(M\times N) \setminus \partial (M\times N)$

$ =(M\times N) \setminus (\partial M)\times N$

$=(M\times N) \cap [(\partial M)\times N]^c$

$=(M\times N) \cap [\big((\partial M)^c\times N\big)\cup \big((\partial M)\times N^c\big) ]$

$=(M\times N) \cap [\big((\text{int}( M)\times N\big)\cup \big((\partial M)\times \emptyset\big) ]$

$=(M\times N) \cap \big(\text{int}( M)\times N\big)$

$=\big( M \cap \text{int}( M)\big)\times N$

$=\text{int}( M)\times N$

Is it correct, please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could have conclude directly from your 2nd equality, noticing that $(p,q) \in \left(M\times N \right) \setminus \left( \partial M\times N\right) \iff p \in M \setminus \partial M,  q\in N$.

Comment: @Didier Thank you! You’re right, that’s much better.